# ¿Cómo separar una String en diferentes longitudes en Python?

Tags: python, string, lista

El objetivo es qué al siguiente String:

```
expresión = "(L1^10)∪L1∪L2^-1"
```

Debo obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
['(','L1','^10',')','∪','L1','∪','L2','^-1']
```

> La condición para decidir los trozos resultantes es que no se debe
> separar los números que le siguen a una "L" mayúscula, y los
> exponentes "^Numero" no deben separarse

No estoy encontrando forma de obtener ese resultado, ¿Cuál es la mejor alternativa para conseguirlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la regla para decidir los trozos resultantes? Alguna regla sintáctica o la mera posición de los caracteres en el string? Si es lo segundo, usa slices. Si es lo primero, probablemente expresiones regulares, pero deberías en ese caso aclarar bien la sintaxis según la cual divides los trozos.

Comment: @abulafia tienes razón, me olvidé de especificar la condición para la separación, ahí actualicé la publicación!

Comment: ¿Por qué se separan ")" de "u"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es difícil encontrar un patrón (expresión regular) utilizable por `re.split()` para que divida por todos los puntos por donde aparezca ese patrón.

También es difícil encontrar una expresión regular que genere los grupos que necesitas, ya que de entrada ni siquiera sabemos cuántos grupos puede llegar a haber.

Pero se me ha ocurrido una solución relativamente sencilla:

1. Mirar si el inicio de la cadena encaja con una expresión regular que denote, bien una L seguida de dígitos, bien un ^ seguido de dígitos (con un - opcional). Esta expresión regular sería `r"L\d+|\^-?\d+"`
2. Si encaja, entonces el trozo encajado es uno de los trozos buscados
3. Si no encaja, entonces simplemente el primer caracter de la cadena es uno de los trozos buscados.
4. La cadena se actualiza para quitarle el trozo que se haya sacado
5. Repetir todo lo anterior hasta que la cadena quede vacía.

El siguiente código implementa esa idea:

```
import re
expresión = "(L1^10)∪L1∪L2^-1"


cadena = expresión
trozos = []
while cadena:
  m = re.match(r"L\d+|\^-?\d+", cadena)
  if m:
    trozo = m.group()
  else:
    trozo = cadena[0]
  trozos.append(trozo)
  cadena = cadena[len(trozo):]
```

El resultado (lista `trozos`) es:

```
['(', 'L1', '^10', ')', '∪', 'L1', '∪', 'L2', '^-1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Ayudándote con la función `findall()` del módulo `re`, y con un patrón bastante similar al de abulafia, puedes obtener la salida que deseas.

El patrón sería el siguiente:

```
L\d+|\^\-?\d+|.
```

El cual, analizándolo, hace:

- `L\d+`: Una letra L seguida de uno o más dígitos

o

- `\^\-?\d+`: El símbolo ^, seguido de (opcionalmente) un signo menos y uno o más números

o

- `.`: Cualquier otra cosa.

Acá es importante conocer la importancia de la precedencia de los elementos del patrón. Se debe colocar el `.` de último para que solo haga match con los elementos que no cumplan los dos criterios precedentes.

Así, podemos tener el siguiente código bastante sencillo:

```
from re import findall


expresión = "(L1^10)∪L1∪L2^-1"
resultado = findall(r'L\d+|\^\-?\d+|.', expresión)
```

En donde `resultado` será una lista que contendrá:

```
['(', 'L1', '^10', ')', '∪', 'L1', '∪', 'L2', '^-1']
```

Comment: Anda mira! Pues pensé yo que con `re.findall()` sería mucho más difícil. +1

Comment: ¡Gracias! Sí, lo que pasa es que mi *rule of thumb* al trabajar con regexes, es que cuando necesito que mi salida sea una lista, generalmente el método que elijo como primera opción es `findall()`. @abulafia